# Join two dataset fields in one cell in report viewer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, rdlc

I am new person in vb.net and MS windows report.
My dataset is addline1, addline2 and addline3 I try to join this three fields on RDLC report addline1 field, but display only addline1. I want to display dataset three address line fields in one cell on report viewer. I typed expression is " =Fields!addline1.Value & Fields!addline2.Value & Fields!addline3.Value ".
Please help me, thanks.